# Permutation test for relationship with R

Tags: correlation, permutation-test

I want to do a permutation test for the significance of a relationship between x and y with a manual function. And I don't want to generate all possible permutations but a sample of them. Before I can compute the p-value I have to generate resamples that are consistent with the null hypothesis of no relationship. My solution for this is the following code:

```
> resamples <- replicate(n, sample(y,size=length(y),replace=FALSE))
```

The problem is, that I am not sure, if this is correct. I read in a book on the internet:

"Choose permutation resamples from the data **without replacement**".

Is it false if the observations (of one sample) are chosen without replacement but not my resamples. Because my function above generates sometimes the same resamples by chance.

Comment: It is unclear what is your question, could you clarify? What is false? What is your question about? Function `sample` takes a **random** sample from a vector of values so it can return duplicated values.

Comment: The phrase "without replacement": is it related to the observations of one resample or means "without replacement" that all resamples have to be different.

Comment: I think you should clarify whether this question is primarily about coding (in which case it would be off-topic here but we could migrate it to Stack Overflow for you - have a look at our [help/on-topic] for more details about what questions are within the scope of our site) or whether your main issue is the underlying statistical one. For what it's worth, I think there is enough statistical content in this question to justify it staying on CV.

Comment: There is a distinction to be made between *bootstrapping* and a *permutation* test: Bootstrapping samples with replacement. A permutation test just shuffles the data in y relative to x so as to break the pairing / relationship between them; for a permutation test, you sample with replacement. Your code is appropriate for a permutation test, but it does not implement bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You ask about meaning of sampling with replacement. Imagine that you have some population that you sample from. When you sample **without replacement**, then each time you randomly sample a case from this population it is removed from the population, so it cannot be sampled any more. When sampling **with replacement**, each time a case is randomly sampled from the population afterwards it is returned back to the population, so it possibly can be sampled again.

This is nicely described in Wikipedia article about [simple random sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample):

> In small populations and often in large ones, such sampling is
>   typically done **"without replacement"**, i.e., one deliberately avoids
>   choosing any member of the population more than once. Although simple
>   random sampling can be conducted **with replacement** instead, this is
>   less common and would normally be described more fully as simple
>   random sampling with replacement. Sampling done without replacement is
>   no longer independent, but still satisfies exchangeability, hence many
>   results still hold. Further, for a small sample from a large
>   population, sampling without replacement is approximately the same as
>   sampling with replacement, since the odds of choosing the same
>   individual twice is low.

As you correctly noticed, in R's `sample` function there is parameter `replace` to declare if you want to sample with (`TRUE`), or without (`FALSE`) replacement.